# The line segment in the euclidean metric

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, metric-spaces

I want to prove that for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^2$ the set $S= \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2: d(a,b)=d(a,x)+d(x,b) \right\}$ coincides with the line segment connecting $a$ and $b$, where $d$ is the euclidean metric.

I was able to prove that, if $x$ lies in the line segment connecting $a$ and $b$, then $x$ also lies in $S$, assuming $x= \lambda a + (1-\lambda) b$ for some $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$.

However, I was not able to prove that every point in $S$ lies in this line segment. It seems to be a little trickier. Can somebody help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Geometric hint: square the equality, then the law of cosines gives that $\cos \widehat{axb} = -1 \iff \widehat{axb} = \pi\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following result is quite elementary, but the algebraic techniques will be reused.

Lemma 1: For all real numbers $a$ and $b$,
$\tag 1 | a + b | \le |a| + |b|$
Moreover, if both $a$ and $b$ are nonzero, then equality holds exactly when both the numbers have the same sign.

Proof
Use the $|c| = \sqrt {c^2}$ formulation for absolute value and after squaring both sides, (1) is deduced from algebra and elementary arithmetic laws.

Lemma 2: For all real numbers $x_1 \text{, } y_1$ and $ x_2 \text{, } y_2$

$\tag 2 \left(x_1^2 + y_1^2\right)\left(x_2^2 + y_2^2\right) - (x_1 x_2 + y_1 y_2)^2 = (x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1)^2$

Proof: Equation (1) is an algebraic identity. QED

Using the Pythagorean distance norm for vectors, the triangle inequality emerges,

Proposition 3: For any two nonzero vectors $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$,

$\tag 3 \|\vec v + \vec w \| \le \| \vec v \| + \| \vec w\|$

Moreover, equality occurs if and only if there exists a unique $\lambda \gt 0$ such that $\vec v = \lambda \vec w$.

Proof
To prove (3), set $\vec v = (x_1,y_1)^t$ and $\vec w = (x_2,y_2)^t$, and apply Lemma 2 with some algebraic technique.

For the second part, begin by assuming both sides of (3) are equal. Then, by Lemma 2, it must be true that
$\tag 4 x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1 = 0$

Since both $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ are nonzero vectors, if say $x_1 = 0$, then $x_2 = 0$ and Lemma 1 can be used. So we can assume that the numbers  $x_1$, $y_1$ and $x_2$, $y_2$ are all nonzero. But then $y_1/y_2 = x_1/x_2$ and by setting $\lambda = y_1/y_2$, (4) will hold true. It can be easily checked that $\lambda$ must be positive for (3) to become an equality.

To show that (3) becomes an equality when $\vec v = \lambda \vec w$ for positive $\lambda$ is straightforward. QED

Since the distance between points is invariant under translations, the OP's question can be equivalently recast as follows,

Proposition 4: Let $\vec u$ be a nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then the line segment connecting $\vec 0$ with $\vec u$ is equal to

$\tag 4 S=\{ \vec s \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \|\vec u\| = \|\vec s\|  + \| \vec u - \vec s\|   \}$

Proof

The line segment is equal to $\{ \alpha \vec u : 0 \le \alpha \le 1 \}$. Apply Proposition 3 and some more algebra to wrap up this proof. QED

---

Observe that the question was answered without using trigonometry or facts about the dot product. But the 'dot product algebra' is encountered in the above derivations, and is a natural way to 'discover' the definition of the inner product.

Answer (score 1):

Take a point $x \in S$,suppose it does lie in the line connecting $a$ and $b$, then $x$, $a$, and $b$ form a triangle hence we will either have

$$d(a,b) > d(a,x) + d(x,b)$$
 or
$$d(a,x) > d(a,b) + d(x,b) \geq d(a,b)$$

or

$$d(x,b) > d(a,b)+d(a,x) \geq d(a,b).$$

In each case, we can find a contradiction with the condition of $x \in S$.

Suppose $x$ doesn't lie in the convex hull of $a$ and $b$.

Then we either have $$d(a,x)=d(a,b)+d(b,x)$$

or $$d(b,x)=d(a,b)+d(a,x).$$

We can find a contradiction in either case.

For example, if $$d(a,x)=d(a,b)+d(b,x)$$

then $d(a,b)=d(a,b)+d(b,x)+d(b,x)$

Hence $x=b$ which contradicts with $x$ does lie in the convex hull of $a$ and $b$.